# Does Google PageSpeed Insight tool use the same results as Lighthouse with my computer or a remote test?

Tags: seo, google

For the Google PageSpeed Insight tool:

1. **LAB Data in Google Speed Insight results** are same like Lighthouse results in my chrome browser? Do they use same formula?
2. **LAB Data in Google Speed Insight** - are they using my computer and network or data are calculated on remote servers?